# Conditional Probability about 2 men lying

Tags: probability

A man is known the speak truth 90℅ of times, another man is known to speak truth 80℅ of times, while reporting the same event. In one interrogation ( performed separately ) is was sure that one of them was lying. What is the probability its the first person lying ?

Comment: What do you think you should do to solve this?  Post your attempt at a solution and people can see how well you are doing and what might be causing you trouble.

Comment: look mate, you don't have to answer if you don't want to, but don't pretend to be a scientist.

Answer (score 1):

The key point in solving this problem is knowledge of [Bayes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes'_theorem). In case of two events it gives us
$$P(B_1\vert A) = \frac{P(A\vert B_1)P(B_1)}{P(A)} = \frac{P(A\vert B_1)P(B_1)}{P(B_1)P(A\vert B_1)+P(B_2)P(A\vert B_2)},$$
where I denote by $A$ the event that somebody lies and by $B_1$ and $B_2$ first and second persons respectively.

Substituting numbers leads to $P(B_1\vert A) = \frac{0,1\cdot0,5}{0,5\cdot0,1+0,5\cdot0,1} = \frac{1}{3}$.

Remark that since second person lies twice as much as first this result is rather intuitively obvious.

Comment: okk. thank you .... Now i understand... my mistake i could not assign the events correctly...